# Understanding disk usage

Tags: 10.04, server, disk-usage

My Ubuntu server is installed on hard drive with very simple partitioning

```
/dev/sdd1   *           1        1824    14647296   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2            1824        3283    11718656   83  Linux
/dev/sdd3            3283        4864    12702720   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So about 14GB is allocated for `/` and about 12GB for `/home`. The rest is swap.

Today I noticed when I login I got a warning that running out of space. `df` shows the following

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1              14G   13G  619M  96% /
none                  2.9G  260K  2.9G   1% /dev
none                  2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
none                  2.9G  852K  2.9G   1% /var/run
none                  2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /var/lock
none                  2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sdd2              12G  2.6G  8.0G  25% /home
```

At this point I am trying to understand what eats 13G on my root partition. `du` shows the following output

```
$ sudo du -hxL --exclude="/home" --max-depth=1 / # excluding home because
                                                  it's other partition

0       /sys
4.0K    /selinux
4.0K    /mnt
447M    /lib
4.0K    /opt
1.9G    /usr
64M     /etc
447M    /lib64
31M     /boot
8.2M    /sbin
8.0K    /man
48K     /root
358M    /var
0       /proc
0       /dev
4.0K    /srv
16K     /lost+found
28K     /tmp
12M     /bin
3.2G    /
```

parted

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 40.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  15.0GB  15.0GB  primary  ext4            boot
 2      15.0GB  27.0GB  12.0GB  primary  ext4
 3      27.0GB  40.0GB  13.0GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

The sum is far not `13G`, in fact it's around `5G`. So what exactly takes space on my root partition?

Comment: Can you try `du -hx / | sort -h` instead?

Comment: Have you rebooted your server recently? If not, it could be a large file that has been deleted, but is still hold by a running process. Thus it won't be visible in the filesystem, but still use diskspace.

Comment: @elmicha: same result (my `sort` doesn't have `-h`)

Comment: @Grumbel: The uptime was just 1 day. There must be some way to list such files. I've also tried to reboot again, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try to boot from a LiveCD. You could examine the filesystems while not being in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet if you umount /dev/sdd2, you will see another 12GB /home folder

Comment: hmm... how to check that without umount? Device is currently actively used and I can't umount it. But you might be right, because `df -x` gave me 2 `4.0K /home` items in output... So what I've done wrong?

Comment: In `fstab` I have 3 mounts, for `/`, `/home` and swap. No double homes...

Comment: `UUID=07476b60-d9da-49ca-b6f8-442713fc112e /home           ext4    defaults        0       2`  <--- could this very last `2` be the one?

Comment: I guess no, it's fschk :(

Comment: Can you check the sizes with `gparted`

Comment: see my original post updated

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in a terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
```

---

OR Try to kill updatedb process

```
$ ps aux | grep updatedb
```

Note the PID.

```
$ kill PID
```

Comment: `ps` shows I don't have `updatedb` running. I try to avoid auto* actions, rather I would like to understand what exactly is eating up the space.